# Is there a way to program a special shortkey to make an ॐ symbol?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro

I see that I can copy and paste this from other text, the ॐ symbol. But I was curious if there was a way I could write a shortcut so that one of my keystroke combinations would produce it. How would I do that on a mac os x?

Let's say the combination was `option + q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "~q" = (insertText:, "ॐ");
}
```

After you quit and reopen applications, option-Q should insert ॐ in most native text views.

You can also create a service like this:

[image]

Then assign the service a keyboard shortcut from System Preferences.

A third option is to create a new keylayout file with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele):

- Choose File > New From Current Input Source. It also assigns the keyboard layout a new ID in newer versions of Ukelele.
- Edit the output of option-Q.
- Save the keyboard layout as a bundle or an XML file to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. Keyboard layouts in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` can't be selected in password dialogs or on the login window. XML keylayout files don't work with the iOS-style popovers shown when holding keys.
- Log out and back in and enable the input source from System Prefefences.

To apply changes to a keylayout file or bundle, run `sudo touch /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/` and log out and back in. You can remove other input sources by [editing the HIToolBox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout/60521#60521).

Comment: First option worked great! Also THANK YOU so much! :)